# Microsoft Edge Chromium, view source, can't use CMD+F (Find)

Tags: macos, microsoft-edge

On macOS Monterey, `Microsoft Edge Chromium Version 98.0.1108.62 (Official build) (arm64)`, I view the source of a webpage, but `CMD + F` does not bring up a Find dialogue, nor is Find available in the menu.

Help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since upgraded to `Version 99.0.1150.39 (Official build) (arm64)` of Microsoft Edge and the problem has gone away.